# How to export text file to csv file using perl?

Tags: perl

I have a system inventory information report in text file, and I want to export them to csv format, how do I do that in Perl? I am new to Perl, just start to learn it.

Here is the text file:

```
Hostname: computer1
OS:       Windows 2008 Server
MemoryGB: 4
CPUcount: 2
DiskSpace:80GB
Location: Cube1

Hostname: computer2
OS:       Windows 2012 Server
MemoryGB: 8
CPUcount: 2
DiskSpace:100GB
Location: Cube2
```

I would to export them into CSV file like the following:

```
Hostname    OS                     MemoryGB    CPUcount    DiskSpace    Location
Computer1   Windows Server 2008       4           2           80GB       Cube1
Computer2   Windows Server 2012       8           2           100GB      Cube2
```

How do I use Perl to do it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I fixed the formatting issue for you. Please don't revert the changes again.

Comment: Hi TLP. First time here, want to make the format right but messed it up. Thank you.

Comment: Well, first you need to open the file for reading and scan line-by-line. Then you generate a dictionary of fields that are based on the string before the colon.

Comment: It seems your records are separated with an empty line. You can use paragraph mode to read them, setting the input record separator to the empty string `$/ = ""`. Then you can split on newline, and split on colon to separate the individual values.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: I suggest you try your best shot at what TLP is suggesting.  If it doesn't work post it either to this question or a new one

Comment: Pity, your input data is only _almost_ yaml data. Otherwise you could use any `YAML` module together with `Text::CSV::Slurp->create` to get it done in about three lines of code.

Comment: A CSV file is *comma-separated*, but there are no commas in your requested output. Are you asking for *tab-separated* output? Please clarify exactly how your output should be formatted.

Comment: Yes, it is a tab-separated output.

Answer (score 0):

```
open ($fh, '<', $inputfile) || die "error reading $inputfile";
while(<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  $line = $_;
  $line =~ s/\s+/ /; # cleanup spaces
  $line =~ s/.*: //; # get rid of headers
  push (@lines, $line);
}
close($fh);

$string = join (",", @lines);
$string =~ s/,,/\n/;
# string has the output, without header
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the fields is consistent, you could use the following awk:

```
awk -F': +' -v OFS="\t" 'BEGIN {
    print "Hostname", "OS", "MemoryGB", "CPUcount", "DiskSpace", "Location"
}
/:/ {printf "%s%c", $2, ($1 == "Location") ? "\n" : "\t"}
'
```